# How do I add custom validation constraints to Entity fields?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to add validation (i.e. constraints) to a field added to a specific (node) entity.

As per documentation here https://drupal.org/node/2015613 i'm trying to change the Field Definition to add a constraint through setPropertyConstraints().

I seem to be able to do so through hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(), but only for base fields, not for fields added with Field UI.

My code so far:

```
function validation_test_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'article') {
    // This works!
    $fields['title']->setPropertyConstraints('value', array('Length' => array('max' => 3)));
    // This doesn't - setPropertyConstraints() doesn't seem to exist
    if (!empty($fields['field_test_field'])) {
      $fields['field_test_field']->setPropertyConstraints('value', array('Length' => array('max' => 3)));
    }
  }
}
```

Though hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter somewhat implies that the $fields array would be FieldDefinition classes (or subclasses), this doesn't seem to be the case? At least the setPropertyConstraints() method is not callable.

I've been debugging for a few hours to find out how this works, but I'm probably missing something obvious. Anyone has any pointers? Am I using the wrong hook or place to try to alter it?

Thanks!
Sven

Comment: See the Fago's answer to similar question here:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/107444/21641

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Looks like we might have to create an issue for that functionality then.

Comment: I created an issue in the issue queue, since it didn't seem to exist yet: https://drupal.org/node/2247085. Cannot comment on the question you linked, since I don't have enough reputation :( I'd like to dive into the issue, but will need some pointers probably.